# How to do Coffee Script Scope highlighting in Atom?

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

How to do Coffee Script Scope highlighting in Atom ?

I don’t know if it would be possible to develop a package that highlights code blocks.
It’s very useful, especially if you have several nested code blocks or for beginners developers.

Answer (score 1):

I Stumbled up on [this post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/show-distinct-spaces-vs-tabs-on-highlight-like-sublime-text/23807) later.

Enabling Settings > Edtor
Enabled **Show Indent Guides** and **Show Invisibles** Is helping me in this.

But there could be better way of heigh lighting block of code with back ground colour.

[image]